# Handle selected UIView in scrollableStack

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uiscrollview, stack

I have created some tabs. The tabs scroll inside the stack horizontaly as expected.

I am trying to add a bottom line (UIView of height = 2.0) to the selected tab (please see image below), and animate the transition of the bottom line as a new tab is selected.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        let center = viewSelected.center        
        let xPointToMove = center.x

        self.animatedView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xPointToMove, y: 0.0)
      })
```

The problem is, that if the user taps the second tab, animatedView only moves a few pixels to the right. I realized that the center.x point of "viewSelected != animatedView" after the animation happens.

Any input on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your "tab" views are subviews of a `UIStackView` ... so their coordinate system (frame, center, etc) is relative to their positions in the stack view.

You need to convert the coordinates.

Try it like this:

```
    // get a reference to the stack view holding viewSelected
    // and a reference to the stack view's superView
    guard let stackV = viewSelected.superview as? UIStackView,
          let stackSV = stackV.superview
    else {
        return
    }
    // convert the frame of viewSelected from the stack view to its superView
    let r = stackV.convert(viewSelected.frame, to: stackSV)
    // animatedView center.x will be the converted frame's .midX
    let xPointToMove = r.midX
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        // animate the view itself, instead of Transforming its layer
        self.animatedView.center.x = xPointToMove
    })
```

---

**Edit** - you may find it easier to use auto-layout constraints instead of setting the frame of the animated view. In addition, using constraints will help keep the animated view positioned and sized correctly if/when the overall view changes size.

Here's a complete example to play with:

```
class MyCustomTabView: UIView {
    
    var selected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            label.textColor = selected ? tintSelectedColor : tintNormalColor
            imgView.tintColor = selected ? tintSelectedColor : tintNormalColor
            backgroundColor = selected ? bkgSelectedColor : bkgNormalColor
        }
    }
    
    let stack = UIStackView()
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()

    let bkgNormalColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9625813365, green: 0.9627193809, blue: 0.9625510573, alpha: 1)
    let bkgSelectedColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9008318782, green: 0.8487855792, blue: 0.9591421485, alpha: 1)
    let tintNormalColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4399604499, green: 0.4400276542, blue: 0.4399457574, alpha: 1)
    let tintSelectedColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3831990361, green: 0.0002554753446, blue: 0.9317755103, alpha: 1)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.spacing = 8
        addSubview(stack)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(imgView)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),
        ])
        label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        label.textColor = tintNormalColor
        imgView.tintColor = tintNormalColor
        backgroundColor = bkgNormalColor
    }
    
}


class MyCustomTabBarView: UIView {
    let stack = UIStackView()
    let animatedView = UIView()
    var avWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var avCenterXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        animatedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(stack)
        addSubview(animatedView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor),
            stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            
            animatedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.bottomAnchor),
            animatedView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2.0),
        ])

        animatedView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 2))
        
        let names: [String] = [
            "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX",
        ]
        
        for (sName, i) in zip(names, Array(1...names.count)) {
            let v = MyCustomTabView()
            v.label.text = "TAB " + sName
            v.imgView.image = UIImage(systemName: "\(i).circle")
            let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tabTapped(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(t)
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

        // position animatedView at tab 0
        if let v = stack.arrangedSubviews.first as? MyCustomTabView {
            avWidthConstraint = animatedView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor)
            avCenterXConstraint = animatedView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerXAnchor)
            avWidthConstraint.isActive = true
            avCenterXConstraint.isActive = true
        }

        animatedView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3831990361, green: 0.0002554753446, blue: 0.9317755103, alpha: 1)

    }
    
    @objc func tabTapped(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        guard let viewSelected = g.view as? MyCustomTabView,
              let n = stack.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: viewSelected)
        else {
            return
        }
        selectTab(n)
    }
    
    // so we can select a tab programmatically from the controller
    func selectTab(_ idx: Int) -> Void {
        // make sure we're not trying to select a tab that doesn't exists
        guard idx > -1, idx < stack.arrangedSubviews.count,
              let viewSelected = stack.arrangedSubviews[idx] as? MyCustomTabView
        else {
            return
        }

        stack.arrangedSubviews.forEach { v in
            if let vv = v as? MyCustomTabView {
                vv.selected = vv == viewSelected
            }
        }
        if avWidthConstraint != nil {
            avWidthConstraint.isActive = false
            avCenterXConstraint.isActive = false
        }
        avWidthConstraint = animatedView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSelected.widthAnchor)
        avCenterXConstraint = animatedView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewSelected.centerXAnchor)
        avWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        avCenterXConstraint.isActive = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

}

class qCheckTVVC: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let myTabsView = MyCustomTabBarView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myTabsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(myTabsView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            
            myTabsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor),
            myTabsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor),
            myTabsView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor),
            myTabsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor),
            myTabsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.heightAnchor),
        ])
        
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! (took me a minute to respond cause I had to put it on pause...). It actually worked (sort of). Meaning, I select the second view, and selectedView moves as planned, IF I scroll to the fifth view and click on it (selectedView does not stays under the second view while scrolling), selectedView goes out of frame (presumably to the coordinates of the fifth view's original spot).

Comment: @JadielAlfonso - *exactly* how you do this will depend on your view hierarchy. Assuming your `animatedView` is a subview of the scrollView, and you have ***not*** given it constraints (that is, has `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`), that code should work.

Comment: @JadielAlfonso - see the **Edit** to my answer. I added a complete example using auto-layout / constraints as a preferable approach.

Comment: Yeah you nailed it. That's exactly the behavior I'm trying to recreate (without highlighting the background). My implementation is, for the most part, the same actually. The only difference seems to be that MyCustomTabBarView for you is a UIView, but for me is a custom layout so layoutIfNeeded() inside the animation won't work for me. Gotta find a workaround to it and that should do it. Love the simplicity of the animation in your implementation btw.

Comment: @JadielAlfonso - in my example code, `MyCustomTabBarView` ***DOES*** have a custom layout: a stack view with an image view and a label. The `layoutIfNeeded()` animates the constraint changes on the `animatedView`. It should have no effect on anything else.

Comment: Got it! self.animatedView.superview?.superview?.layoutIfNeeded() works! THANKS again! Learned a lot with this one :))))))